# Laravel relationships hasMany updateOrCreate array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have `User` model which has relationships `hasMany` with `UserPosition` eloquent model:

**User model**

```
public function positions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserPosition::class);
}
```

How I can use `updateOrCreate` method when from request come `array` of data positions?

**Code**

```
$positions = [
    "doctor",
    "developer"
];

$user->positions()->each(function($position) use ($positions, $user) {
    $id = $user->id;
    foreach ($positions as $name) {
        $position->updateOrCreate(['user_id' => $id, 'name' => $name], [
            'name' => $name
        ]);
    }
});
```

> **Note:** In this example user doesn't has any positions on the table of database

But my code not work. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating on the existing positions of a user, meaning that if a user has no positions the iteration will never happen. You can iterate along the positions you need to make:

```
$positions = collect([
    "doctor",
    "developer"
]);

$positions->each(function($position) use ($user) {
        $user->positions()->updateOrCreate(['name' => $position], [
            'name' => $position
        ]);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're do this without looping? I think what `$name` here is `undefined` am I right? I must replace var `$name` wiht `$position` in your case? @apokryfos

Comment: Yes you're right. There is still looping being done but it's over the `$positions` collection

Comment: I don't see why this is the excepted answer, `updateOrCreate()` won't work on a collection of models and `$user->positions()` is returning a collection, in order for this to work you must use `firstOrCreate()` directly on the Position model class, like I defined in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your running your `updateOrCreate()` method inside an each iteration which never runs because as you stated in your note "this example user doesn't has any positions on the table of database"

Here your trying to loop through your currently existing positions attached to your user model:

```
$user->positions()->each()
```

But that won't run because the user doesn't have any positions at the moment.

I'm guessing you are trying to update the the user's positions, where it is possible that the user already has one or more of those positions associated to him and you don't want to create duplicates, for that you can do this:

```
$positions = [
    "doctor",
    "developer"
];

foreach($positions as $position) {
    UserPosition::firstOrCreate(['user_id' => $user->id, 'name' => $position]);
}
```